# Add selected elements to list using for loop

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add the integers 6 from 30, except for 22 and 26, to a List using a for loop. But 22 and 26 are still being added. What did I do wrong?

```
List<int> lineNumbers = new List<int>();

for (int x = 6; x < 30; x++)
{
  if ((x != 22) || (x != 26))
  {
    lineNumbers.Add(x);                  
  }               
}
```

The two integers are not added if the code is like below:

```
for (int x = 6; x < 30; x++)
{
  if (x == 22 )
  {
  }
  else if (x == 26)
  {
  }
  else
  {
    lineNumbers.Add(x);              
  }
}
```

Comment: You said "except for 22 **and** 26" but your code is doing `||` which is or.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the `||` with `&&`:

```
for (int x = 6; x < 30; x++)
{
  if ((x != 22) && (x != 26))
  {
    lineNumbers.Add(x);                  
  }               
}
```

Or perhaps, to be more clear:

```
for (int x = 6; x < 30; x++)
{
  if ((x == 22) || (x == 26))
    continue;

  lineNumbers.Add(x);
}
```

Alternatively, you could perform this as a one-liner using LINQ. This isn't necessarily faster or anything, so if your `for` loop is clearer to you, then keep it as-is.

```
lineNumbers.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(6, 24).Except(new[] { 22, 26 }));
```

Comment: Thanks for providing three options. The upper range limit is 24, rather than 25, since 30 is excluded.

Answer (score 1):

Change your conditions. Use `&&` instead of `||`

```
if ((x != 22) && (x != 26))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `&&` instead of `||` because you want to match between both conditions.

```
if ((x != 22) && (x != 26))
```

You can also do this using `LINQ` (not necessarily but I like LINQ :)

```
var lineNumbers = Enumerable.Range(6, 30).Except(new[] {22, 26}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if ((x != 22) || (x != 26))` to `if ((x != 22) && (x != 26))`

Or you can use continue like below :

```
for (int x = 6; x < 30; x++)
{
   if ((x == 22) || (x == 26))
       continue;
   else
       lineNumbers.Add(x);                                  
}
```